# According to Origin, what exactly happens to people when they die?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

According to Origin, what happens to followers of Origin when they die?  Are they ascended to the same plane as the Ori, making them Ori too?  Or are they ascended to a lower plane than the plane of the Ori, which still gives them immortality but doesn't give them as much power as an Ori?

**According to Origin, what happens to unbelievers when they die?**  Do they simply cease to exist, going into a never-ending state of nothingness?  Or are they all cast to hell, to burn forever "in the fires of eternal damnation"?

Comment: Hallowed ***are*** the Ori.

Comment: They for sure do not become ori(as they are all a faction of the ascended ancients), in reality they go where ever normal humans go. Ill have to see if i can find exactly what the origin says they do however.

Comment: Interestingly, in the Origin tradition, fire isn't associated with damnation, it's associated with the "light of enlightenment".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### All who follow the words of the Ori shall become ascended, and dwell with the Ori on the Planes of Enlightenment, immortal and perfect.

**So sayeth the [Story of Markon](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Markon), from the Book of Origin**.

> *"So Markon prayed for forgiveness and took the first step. **And the hands of the Ori enveloped all those who welcomed him back.**"*

**So sayeth the [words of the Prior](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s9/transcripts/903.shtml)**.

> *"Guide us on the path that we may triumph over the enemy of our
>   salvation **and be with you in the end of ends on the planes of
>   enlightenment.**"*

**And rejoice at the [words of the risen Ori](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s9/transcripts/903.shtml)!**

> **Doci/Ori:** *We are their creators. **All who follow the path will join
>   us in enlightenment.***

---

Those whose minds are poisoned by unbelievers will dwell in torment until those that put them astray have been destroyed, at which point their wretched existence will be extinguished.

**Heed the [wisdom](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/9.11_%22The_Fourth_Horseman_Part_2%22_Transcript) of a Prior of the Ori.**

> ***"And the souls of their victims knew no peace***, until the Ori came and
>   whispered to them: 'Sleep, for the end draws near!' And on that day
>   all will rejoice, when the Ori come and lay them low."

### Hallowed are the Ori.

Comment: For the record, Orlin says that nothing happens. That when you die, you just die. That may, of course just be Alteran propaganda.

Comment: Except it was all false. One of the original pretenses of the Ori Arc is that the Ori are obsessed with power, and to help other beings to ascend would mean they would have to share that power between more bodies. (The source of their power was believers/followers, hence when they discover the Milky Way galaxy filled with humans they send a great fleet to 'convert' the people to the Ori religion).

Comment: @Robotnik Heh, I was ready to write up an answer about that earlier, then realized the question is angled away from "what actually happens" and towards "what are they told?"

Comment: @Izkata - I was too, but I still felt it worth mentioning, even in comment form :)